# How to load a json data file into a variable in robot framework!? with

Tags: json, robotframework

I Am trying to load a JSON data file into a variable directly in Robot Framework. Can anyone please elaborate with an e.g. giving the exact syntax as to how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install HTTPLibrary: https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary

Create `JsonLib.py`:

```
from HttpLibrary import HTTP


class JsonLib(object):

    def load_json_data_from_file(self, filepath):
        """ Don't forget to document the keyword!!!
        """
        json_string = open(filepath).read()
        HTTP().should_be_valid_json(json_string)
        return json_string
```

Import and call it in you RF code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    JsonLib.py

*** Test Cases ***
Do Whatever With My Json
    [Documentation]    Don't forget to document what your test does!!!
    ${my_json}    Load JSON Data From File    ${/}foo{/}bar.json
```

Comment: how about with the format of the filepath on Windows?

Comment: ah... I did't think abot that... fixed according to the RF doc

Comment: *** Settings ***
Library   JsonLib.py

*** Test Cases ***
Do Whatever With My Json
    [Documentation]   Don't forget to document what your test does!!!
    ${my_json}     Load JSON DATA From File     ./cookie.json

Comment: r u  miss  a ‘$’  before  '{my_json}' ,i tried use this,successed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ah... thx, (written from phone or so...), fixed